# How to best share routes between Rails app and Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing my first "real" Rails app after making a few successful learning projects and I'm still a little bit iffy on best practises for App vs API routes. Ideally, API routes will be RESTful, mainly revolving around using `resources :articles` or whatever, but I'm wondering which of the the following two scenarios is best

- Create the app itself using RESTful routes, then bolt on an API in the "api" namespace/subdomain for example, and after authentication, piggy back off the same routes (not sure exactly how to do the piggy backing yet with different authentication, but that will come later. Or;
- Create the app itself with whatever routes are semantic and work well (still ideally CRUD based), then create an entirely new set of controllers and routes for the API (RESTful)

I appreciate any feedback that anyone has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default "Rails way" is to make your models available to different clients through a single set of URIs, handled by a single set of controllers — /articles for browsers, /articles.json or /articles.xml for programmatic access. You can see that in Rails' emphasis on "resources", the `respond_to` mechanism in your controllers and so on.

This often works very well for simpler APIs that match the CRUD semantics closely. If yours for whatever reason does not, you might be better off with separating it out.

Try starting out the simple way by sticking to this 'one controller for both' approach. If you like, you could use

```
scope '(api)' do
  resources :articles
  resources :authors
  resources :comments
  # ...
end
```

to add an optional '/api/' path segment to your URLs - in this case, giving you both `/api/articles` and `/articles`, routed to the same controller. This gives you an easy way out, should you later decide to switch to separate controllers for HTML and API access.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it was 100% what I was looking for! I'm sort of familiar with `respond_to`, but I don't really like having `respond_to` blocks in every controller action. To me it seems ugly, but I certainly appreciate the "one size fits all" approach. I think I'll end up having a separate set of controllers for API requests, it just seems cleaner and more satisfying to me. We'll see though!

Comment: @texelate I use `respond_with` everywhere, which is very neat and removes the need to have these repetitive `respond_to` definitions everywhere. I did not mention it, though, since it was just removed from Rails core in the latest 4.2.0 and extracted into the [responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders). Take a look at [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) if you're interested.

Comment: Cool! So how exactly is a view rendered when `respond_with @variable` is responding to HTML? Is the view rendered and `@variable` is basically ignored (but of course carries through to the view as an instance variable)?

Comment: @texelate `respond_with` automates all the usual song and dance you would usually do manually — _"redirect to the show action after a successful update, otherwise render the 'edit' view again"_, _"redirect to index after a resource is deleted"_ and so on. It uses the resource in @variable to figure out what to do — depending on whether it has errors or not, is newly created or updated etc. _"Ah, this is a new, unsaved object with errors on it? We must be in the middle of a `create` that failed, so I'll render the `new` template again"_.